# SaveChanges() not working in production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, signalr

I have this simple code inside a SignalR hub, and it works fine when running the code on my machine.

```
using (var db = new dbEntities())
{
    var registry = db.myTable.Where( /* where clause */ ).FirstOrDefault();
    registry.status = "C";
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

But when I publish the website and upload it to the server, this code does not save the changes on the database. 
Other places that modifies the database are working just fine, but this one that is inside a signalR hub does not.

Comment: So, what _does_ happen?

Comment: 1 - do you mean `registry.status = "C";` (missing the y)? 2- are you sure your code is actually being called? 3- are you sure you are connecting to the correct database?

Comment: Side note - you can replace the `Where` clause with the `FirstOrDefault`. `var registry = db.myTable.FirstOrDefault( /* where clause */ );`

Comment: About the registry, it was just a typo, my actual code does not use those names.
I am sure that the code is being called, because just after this block there is a call to a client side method that is working just fine. And the database connection is correct, because the code gets info from there through the same dbContext.

Comment: Have you marked your entity as modified `db.Entry(registry).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;` ?

Comment: Tried that already, does not seems to work. And it works without it when running local.

Comment: @LuizEduardoSimões You actually don't need to mark the Entity as modified, since you are fetching it from the same context, EF is aware of the changes. Does the user executing the action on the database has the necessary permissions? Does other write operations in the system works?

Comment: You have a potential `NullReferenceException` here if the where clause ends up causing nothing to match. Then, `registry` is null, and null does not a have a member named `status`. You didn't mention any exceptions, but even if this isn't your current issue, you should fix it post haste.

Comment: Are you sure the hub is set up correctly? Did you check if the message conveys?

Answer (score 0):

Its likely that your user does not have permissions to update the database you are using on the productions box. Check your application event logs on your server for errors, and make sure the user that you are using for you applications has appropriate permissions on the database and IIS server.